# PHP framework with good user login/admin

Tags: php, codeigniter, kohana, kohana-auth

I am looking for a good PHP framework with a good user login & admin.  I have looked at Codeigniter, but the user admins I have found seem dated.  I have been looking at at Kohana, but have not been able to find a viable login / admin pannel?  I basically need:

- User login
- User verification of new user
- User p/w reset
- Admin add/edit/del user
- Admin user grouping

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[BackEndPro](http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro) for CodeIgniter.

Includes:

- User Authentication with registration & account activation
- User Permissions by using ACL (Access Control Lists)
- Admin GUI backend for editing Site-wide Preferences
- Built on Matchbox (for Modular development)
- Asset Library (optimize, cache and load JS & CSS)
- ReCAPTCHA
- Status messages (info/success/warning/error messages for the user)

Comment: Aargh! Sorry Mitchell, I've down voted you by mistake whilst trying to click the link to bep on my little iPhone screen. It doesn't seem to let me reverse the vote! Any ideas?!

Comment: I've edited the answer, which I think will allow you to change your vote now? Appreciate you going out of your way to fix your vote!

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to [php-login](http://php-login.net)

It does exactly what you are searching for !

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are frameworks that give you the tools to build it yourself by giving you access to models of your database object, controllers and views for your application logic and html templates.

If you want a ready made one, [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) can get you started with its [scaffolding](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/14-Generators) that creates simple CRUD (Create Retrieve Update Delete) html forms for the models defined in it, but you will need to modify it to adapt to your own needs.

I wonder if you wouldn't be better served with a full fledged CMS, such as [Drupal](http://drupal.org) which has a full admin panel, user management etc out of the box.